# Centering Joomla template on Mobile Device

Tags: templates, mobile, joomla, center

While it displays correctly on a PC, viewing it on my android phone and ipod touch it is aligned to the left and cuts of a part of the content. How can I display it in the center?

I read something that you can add meta tags to it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

but how can I add these to the template?

Thank you in advance

site link: www.alohaspot.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions > Template Manager
Click on the default site template name, NOT style name to edit and then click on "Edit main page template", search for HEAD tag and insert your META there and save.

Good luck.